# How to make a dictionary from another dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, something like this

```
input = [
    {"0_question": "how are you"}, 
    {"0_answer": "good"},
    {"4_question": "what time is it"},
    {"4_answer": "morning"},
]
```

and I want this:

```
expected_result = {
    0: {"how are you": "good"},
    4: {"what time is it" : "morning"},
}
```

this is what I tried:

```
x = {}
l= []
for i, d in enumerate(a):
    for k, v in d.items():
        l.append(v)
    x[l[i]] = l[i+1]
```

Comment: "I tried multiple ways but no success" you should show us.

Comment: By the way, ```input``` is a built-in function. Better avoid using them as variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Split the original `dict key` into numeric and type part:

```
a = [
    {
        "0_question": "how are you"
    }, {
        "0_answer": "good"
    }, {
        "4_question": "what time is it"
    }, {
        "4_answer": "morning"
    }
]

dic = {}

for item in a:
    value = list(item.values())[0]
    num, itemType = list(item.keys())[0].split('_')
    num = int(num)

    if itemType == 'question':
        dic[num] = {value: ''}
    else:
        key = list(dic[num].keys())[0]
        dic[num][key] = value
print(dic)
```

Out:

```
{0: {'how are you': 'good'}, 4: {'what time is it': 'morning'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [nested loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_nested.asp) and the modulo operator (`%`). Use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) to find the question/answer number:

```py
import re

l = [
    {"0_question": "how are you"},
    {"0_answer": "good"},
    {"4_question": "what time is it"},
    {"4_answer": "morning"},
    {"157_question": "which fruit do you want"},
    {"157_answer": "apple"}
]
new_d = {}
for i, d in enumerate(l):
    for k, v in d.items():
        result = re.search("\d+", k).group(0)
        num = int(result)

        if ((i + 1) % 2) == 0:
            for new_k in new_d[num].keys():
                new_d[num][new_k] = v
        else:
            new_d[num] = {v: ""}

print(new_d)
```

Output

```
{0: {'how are you': 'good'}, 4: {'what time is it': 'morning'}, 157: {'which fruit do you want': 'apple'}}
```

Comment: Will only work for numbers less than 10, what if `"157_question"`?

Comment: I got a key error with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
a = [{"0_question": "how are you"},
     {"0_answer": "good"},
     {"4_question": "what time is it"},
     {"4_answer": "morning"}]


dic = {}

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        dic[list(a[i].keys())[0]] = {list(a[i].values())[0]: list(a[i + 1].values())[0]}

print(dic)
```

Comment: Hey Farhad, welcome to the site! I think this solution is a bit brittle. You're relying on the questions and answered alternating back and forth. I think a more resilient solution would look for `question` and `answer` in the keys.

Comment: Will only work for numbers less than 10, what if "157_question"?

Comment: Note, that does not produce the exact output as wanted: `{'0_question': {'how are you': 'good'}, '4_question': {'what time is it': 'morning'}}`

Answer (score 0):

This has fewer lines and hopefully increases readability. The downside is it uses more resources by restructuring the initial data.

```
sample_data = [{"0_question" : "how are you"},
{"0_answer": "good"},
{"4_question" : "what time is it"},
{"4_answer": "morning"}]

restructured_data = {k: v for data in sample_data for k, v in data.items()}
nums = list(set([int(k.split("_")[0]) for k, v in restructured_data.items()]))
new_dict = {num: {restructured_data[f'{num}_question']: restructured_data[f'{num}_answer']} for num in nums}

print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{0: {'how are you': 'good'}, 4: {'what time is it': 'morning'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{"0_question" : "how are you"}, 
        {"0_answer": "good"},
        {"4_question" : "what time is it"},
        {"4_answer": "morning"}]
        
# unpack dict values into any iterable data structure
# list in my case
unpacked_data = list(map(lambda dict_: list(dict_.items()), data))

# dict_items is not subscriptable, so unpack it again
# also exctracting number from key.
processed_data = list(
                        map(
                            lambda values_tuple: (values_tuple[0][0][0], values_tuple[0][1]),
                            unpacked_data
                            )
                    )

result_dict = {}

# according to input data we assuame that there is a pairs of (question: answer).
# using zip and slicing for pair iteration
for question, answer in zip(processed_data[0::2], processed_data[1::2]):
    result_dict[question[0]] = {question[1] : answer[1]}
    
print(result_dict)
```

UPD: this may be not the most optimal solution, but i hope that is pretty clear
for understanding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Code:

```
{ int(list(i1)[0][0]) : {list(i1.values())[0] : list(i2.values())[0] } for i1, i2 in zip(input[::2], input[1::2])}
```

Output:

[image]